# Issues with the TabBar and NavigationBar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have two view controller in the TabBar. I set up like if user is logged in then it's directly show the TabBar else it's showing loginViewController. Look the Code in `AppDelegate`

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: ["NSApplicationCrashOnExceptions": true])

        let status = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "status")

        //StoryBoard Decide
        if (status == false){
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Tools", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)
            let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        }else {
            let storyBoard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Tools", bundle:nil)
            let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as! UITabBarController
            let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)
            let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
            appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
        }}
```

But when it's work proper when i go through login ViewController but when user is alredy logged in it's showing the navigation bar in the HomeViewController.

[image]

This is my storyBoard Setup.
[image]

And also how to manage the Navigation with TabBar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are making new navigation controller then add tabbar as its root view.

Instead of making UINavigationController you can do this:

Replace

```
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as! UITabBarController
let navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: nextViewController)
let appdelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
appdelegate.window!.rootViewController = navigationController
```

with:

```
let nextViewController = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "tabbar") as! UITabBarController
self.window?.rootViewController = nextViewController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Oh great you save my time. Can you please explain

Comment: And i have table in my moreViewController and with `Didselect` i push the ViewController but it's not working properly

Comment: I explained it at two first rows. What should I explain in more detail ?
Also you can ask you second question as new question.